# Measuring absolute distance and velocity using self-mixing laser signal beat frequency

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, laser, measurements, interference

In function $D=\frac{c}{4\left|\dot{v}_{s}\right|}\left[\frac{\sigma_{2}\left(N_{2}-1\right)}{\Delta t_{2}}-\frac{\sigma_{1}\left(N_{1}-1\right)}{\Delta t_{1}}\right]$ from [formula 8 on p.6686](https://scihub.bban.top/10.1364/AO.37.006684)  $v_{s}$ is defined as optical frequency, but what does $\dot{v}_{s}$ stands for?

If you check [formula 8 on page 104](https://scihub.bban.top/10.1117/12.312977) $D=\frac{c}{4\left(\frac{d v}{d t}\right)}\left(\sigma_{0} f_{b 0}+\sigma_{1} f_{b 1}\right)$ wich apparently references previous one. IMHO $f_{b 0}$ and $f_{b 1}$ in latter correspond to $\frac{N_{0}-1}{\Delta t_{0}}$ and $\frac{N_{1}-1}{\Delta t_{1}}$ from former formula respectively. And $\frac{d v}{d t}$ apparently corresponds to $\dot{v}_{s}$. And yet it's not much cleared what $\dot{v}_{s}$ stands for.

## Update

If one loks at [formula 4 on p.6683](https://scihub.bban.top/10.1364/AO.37.006684) and sentence before it becomes clear that $\dot{P_c}$ is deriviative of $P_c$. So $\frac{d v}{d t}$ indeed corresponds to $\dot{v}_{s}$ as a deriviative ([Newtons or dot notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Newton's_notation)). And my guess is that $\dot{v}_{s}$ should mean the linear change of the signal frequency derived from linear change of the wavelength due to modulation. Moreover $v_{s}$ [is defined (p.6685)](https://scihub.bban.top/10.1364/AO.37.006684) as "emission frequency without feedback"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\dot{v}_{s}$ is equal to $\Delta v_{pp}$ (modulated optical frequency (Hz)) divided by half of $T_i$ (time of triangular injection current [Fig. 2 on p. 6685](https://scihub.bban.top/10.1364/AO.37.006684) (s)). $$\dot{v}_{s}=\frac{\Delta v_{pp}}{\frac{T_i}{2}}$$